# Non finitely-generated projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, projective-module

> Let $M$ be a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Must $M$ be free?

It is easy to see that the answer is yes if $M$ is finitely generated, but I do not know about the general case.

> If the answer is "yes" (which would surprise me), is the same true for Dedekind domains?

Comment: Any subgroup of a free abelian group is free.

Comment: @egreg: Is that true for non-finitely-generated subgroups?  One has to be careful here; for instance, direct limits of free abelian groups need not be free.

Comment: That's well known: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group#Subgroups The result requires the axiom of choice, of course.

Comment: @egreg: OK, thanks.  The portion of my question about Dedekind domains remains open.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/671635/62967 Infinintely generated projective modules over a noetherian domain are free. This is generally false for finitely generated projective modules over Dedekind domains, because any ideal is projective as a module.

Comment: @egreg: You're right, in my haste I had forgotten to assume that said Dedekind domain has trivial ideal class group.  Pete Clark's answer to that question finishes off my question.