# Flat Non Projective $A$-Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

A standard fact in Commutative Algebra is that a Projective $A$-module is flat.

The converse is false.

> Can someone show me an example of a Flat Non Projective $A$-Module?

Thank you!

Comment: @user26857 thanks, done.

Comment: Proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module: See Problem 4 (part b) in [this link.](http://www.math.umd.edu/old/graduate/exams/Math600/alg-summer01-sol.pdf)

Comment: Joseph, here is another example of flat module that is not projective. Take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ (localization at the prime ideal $(2)$). Then $M$ is a flat $A$-module, but it is not projective. See the last page (problem 14) of [this document](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~tfylam/Math221/6.pdf) for the details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An elementary proof that $\mathbf Q$ is not projective over $\mathbf Z$: if $\mathbf Q$ were projective, it would be a direct summand of a free $\mathbf Z$-module $L$, hence there would be an injective homomorphism from $\mathbf Q$ into $L$.

However the only homorphism from $\mathbf Q$ into a free module is the null homomorphism: indeed, for any $n$, and any homomorphism $f\colon \mathbf Q\to L$, we have
$$f(1)=2^nf\Bigl(\dfrac1{2^n}\Bigr)\in 2^n L,\quad\text{hence}\quad f(1)\in\bigcap_{n\ge 0}2^n L=0.$$
Since $f(1)=0$, it is easy to deduce $f\Bigl(\dfrac ab\Bigr)=0\;$ for any $\;\dfrac ab\in\mathbf Q$.

Comment: This looks like a nice proof. Could you justify why $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} 2^{n}L=0$? If $x\in 2^{n}L$ for each $n\geq 1$, this means $x=2^{n} a_{n}$ for some $a_n\in L$. How do we get a contradiction if $x\neq 0$?

Comment: This is just because on each component of $L\simeq \mathbf Z^{(I)}$ the $i$-th coordinate of $x$ lies in $\bigcap\limits_n 2^n\mathbf Z$, and this one is $0$.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. +1. Also, we could have written $n$ instead of $2^{n}$ throughout the solution, right?

Comment: Yes, we could, but I think it would have been  more complicated, as the ideals $n\mathbf Z$ are not linearly ordered.

Answer (score 1):

The rationals as a module over the integers is flat but not projective.

Comment: Can you explain better you answer giving an explicit proof?

Comment: @JosephCurwen: You may find this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671545/projective-module-over-a-pid-is-free) helpful.