# $R$ is a PID and $M=R/(d)$ an $R$-module. Show that $M$ is not projective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

Note: $(d)$ is a nonzero proper ideal of $R$.

**My attempt:**

Consider $\pi:R\to R/(d)$, then $\ker(\pi)=(d)$. I want to prove that there is no $\sigma:R/(d)\to R$ such that $\pi\circ \sigma=id_M$.

Suppose that such a $\sigma$ exists, then $R\cong (d) \oplus R/(d)$. I'm not entirely sure if this is a contradiction. I know that the ideals of $R/(d)$ are the (principal) ideals of $R$ that contain $(d)$, but other than that I don't really see where I could use the fact that $R$ is a PID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from where you ended, $R\cong (d)\oplus R/(d) $ you could refine it to say that actually $R=(d)\oplus N$ (an internal direct sum). Since a domain has no proper summands, $(d)=\{0\}$ or $(d)=R$.

Both cases are just fine, since both $\{0\}$ and $R$ are projective, but presumably you wanted a nonzero, proper ideal $(d)$.

In fact, the same reasoning shows you $R/I$ is not projective for any nontrivial ideal $I$ in a *domain*, or even more generally, any uniform ring.

---

Another way:

A [projective module over a PID is free](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/671545/29335), and a nonzero free module is faithful (i.e. has trivial annihilator) but $M$ is clearly annihilated by $d$.  (Again, I exclude $(d)$ equal to $\{0\}$ or $R$, which I guess you omitted unintentionally.)

Comment: Thank you so much! The question does not state what $(d)$ can't be, but I also assumed that it had to be a nonzero, proper ideal; I'll edit the question for future readers. I am a little confused with the first paragraph though: 1) how did you go from a quotient to a module N (?), are you using the fact that $R/I$ ($I\trianglelefteq R$) is an $R$-module? 2) why can't a domain have proper summands?

Comment: @Zachary When the first map is the inclusion map, the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) says that when $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ splits, $A$ is actually an internal direct summand of $B$.  What you said is true, of course, that $R/(d)$ is an (external) direct sum of $(d)$ and $R/(d)$, but I wanted to sharpen that to talk about an actual internal summand of $R$.  A domain obviously can't be expressed as $A\oplus B=R$ for nonzero ideals $A,B$. How could $A\cap B=\{0\}$ when $AB\neq\{0\}$?

Comment: Ok, I get it now! Thank you.

Comment: @Zachary No problem!